# vue global components with kebab case

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to globally register my frequently used components.
I have started using kebab casing because I am splitting my css, js and vue files up so I want to modify my existing registration script which looked like this:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import upperFirst from "lodash/upperFirst";
import camelCase from "lodash/camelCase";

const requireComponent = require.context(
  // The relative path of the components folder
  "./components",
  // Whether or not to look in subfolders
  false,
  // The regular expression used to match base component filenames
  /Base[A-Z]\w+\.(vue|js)$/
);

requireComponent.keys().forEach((fileName) => {
  // Get component config
  const componentConfig = requireComponent(fileName);

  // Get PascalCase name of component
  const componentName = upperFirst(
    camelCase(
      // Gets the file name regardless of folder depth
      fileName
        .split("/")
        .pop()
        .replace(/\.\w+$/, "")
    )
  );

  // Register component globally
  Vue.component(
    componentName,
    // Look for the component options on `.default`, which will
    // exist if the component was exported with `export default`,
    // otherwise fall back to module's root.
    componentConfig.default || componentConfig
  );
});
```

I have since found another here:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bencodezen/vue-enterprise-boilerplate/main/src/components/_globals.js

which I have modified and changed it to this:

```
// Globally register all base components for convenience, because they
// will be used very frequently. Components are registered using the
// PascalCased version of their file name.

import Vue from "vue";

// https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context
const requireComponent = require.context(
  // Look for files in the current directory
  "./components",
  // Do not look in subdirectories
  true,
  // Only include "_base-" prefixed .vue files
  /base-[\w-]+\.vue$/
);

// For each matching file name...
requireComponent.keys().forEach((fileName) => {
  // Get the component config
  const componentConfig = requireComponent(fileName);
  // Get the PascalCase version of the component name
  const componentName = fileName
    // Remove the file extension from the end
    .replace(/\.\w+$/, "")
    // Split up kebabs
    .split("-")
    // Upper case
    .map((kebab) => kebab.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + kebab.slice(1))
    // Concatenated
    .join("");

  console.log(componentName);

  // Globally register the component
  Vue.component(componentName, componentConfig.default || componentConfig);
});
```

But if I try to use my components, they don't work.
I have this simple one defined like this:

```
import { defineComponent } from "@vue/composition-api";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "BaseToggle",
  props: {
    open: {
      type: Boolean,
    },
    color: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
});
```

and if I try to use it in any other component like this:

```
<base-toggle color="white" />
```

or even

```
<BaseToggle color="white" />
```

I get this error:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what might be going wrong?

---

The component is split into 3 files

- base-toggle.component.scss
- base-toggle.component.ts
- base-toggle.component.vue

and it exists in folder `./components/base-toggle`.
So I have updated my script to this:

```
// Globally register all base components for convenience, because they
// will be used very frequently. Components are registered using the
// PascalCased version of their file name.

import Vue from "vue";

// https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context
const requireComponent = require.context(
  // Look for files in the current directory
  "./components",
  // Do not look in subdirectories
  true,
  // Only include "_base-" prefixed .vue files
  /base-[\w-]+\.component.vue$/
);

// For each matching file name...
requireComponent.keys().forEach((fileName) => {
  // Get the component config
  const componentConfig = requireComponent(fileName);
  // Get the PascalCase version of the component name
  const componentName = fileName
    // Remove the file extension from the end
    .replace(".component.vue", "")
    // Split up kebabs
    .split("-")
    // Upper case
    .map((kebab) => kebab.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + kebab.slice(1))
    // Concatenated
    .join("");

  console.log(componentName);

  // Globally register the component
  Vue.component(componentName, componentConfig.default || componentConfig);
});
```

But this is still not working.

Comment: Maybe casing issue? What is the name of the file with the `base-toggle` component ?

Comment: base-toggle.component.vue and I have tried updating the registration script to `/base-[\w-]+\.component.vue$/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was because of the folder. I updated my script to this:

```
// Globally register all base components for convenience, because they
// will be used very frequently. Components are registered using the
// PascalCased version of their file name.

import Vue from "vue";

// https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context
const requireComponent = require.context(
  // Look for files in the current directory
  "../components",
  // Do not look in subdirectories
  true,
  // Only include "_base-" prefixed .vue files
  /base-[\w\-.]+\.vue$/
);

// For each matching file name...
requireComponent.keys().forEach((fileName) => {
  // Get the component config
  const componentConfig = requireComponent(fileName);
  // Get the PascalCase version of the component name
  const componentName = fileName
    // Remove any folder name
    .split("/")[1]
    // Remove the file extension from the end
    .replace(".component.vue", "")
    // Split up kebabs
    .split("-")
    // Upper case
    .map((kebab) => kebab.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + kebab.slice(1))
    // Concatenated
    .join("");

  console.log(componentName);

  // Globally register the component
  Vue.component(componentName, componentConfig.default || componentConfig);
});
```

With the help of @Michal, I changed the regex, so now it's this:

```
// Globally register all base components for convenience, because they
// will be used very frequently. Components are registered using the
// PascalCased version of their file name.

import Vue from "vue";

// https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context
const requireComponent = require.context(
  // Look for files in the current directory
  "../components",
  // Do not look in subdirectories
  true,
  // Only include "_base-" prefixed .vue files
  /base-[\w-.]+\.vue$/
);

// For each matching file name...
requireComponent.keys().forEach((fileName) => {
  // Get the component config
  const componentConfig = requireComponent(fileName);
  // Get the PascalCase version of the component name
  const componentName = fileName
    // Remove any folder name
    .split("/")[1]
    // Remove the file extension from the end
    .replace(/\.\w+$/, "")
    // Split up kebabs
    .split("-")
    // Upper case
    .map((kebab) => kebab.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + kebab.slice(1))
    // Concatenated
    .join("");

  console.log(componentName);

  // Globally register the component
  Vue.component(componentName, componentConfig.default || componentConfig);
});
```